# Understanding Sequence and Column in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a DF as following:

```
+-------+----------+
|  value|     group|
+-------+----------+
|      A|         X|
|      A|         X|
|      A|         X|
|      A|         X|
|      B|         Z|
|      B|         Z|
|      B|         Z|
+-------+----------+
```

What I am trying to do is add 5(for example) more rows of each value,group combination to the dataframe. I tried exploring sequence and explode but couldn't get the method signatures(didn't understand why they took Column as inputs). How can I achieve this task.

Edit: This can be acheived by selecting `functions.explode(functions.sequence(functions.lit(1),functions.lit(5),functions.lit(1)` and doing union with the original dataframe. Is there an efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame in Spark is immutable. Therefore, you could only achieve what you want by combining 2 DataFrames (one is as you posted, the other one is your intention) in a vertical way (`union`), OR add the data you want into data source via a native programming language such as Python.

In this scenario, you make the intentional data manipulation via an API you are familiar with.
*Scala APIs*

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => f}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits

val originalDf = ... // your example DF
val addition = originalDf.select($"value").distinct()\
    .select($"value", f.explode_outer(f.sequence(f.lit(0), f.lit(5), f.lit(1))).alias("group"))
val result1 = originalDf.union(addition)
```

*Plain SQL*

```scala
val originalDf = .... // your example DF
originalDf.createOrReplaceTempView("originalDf")
val result2 = spark.sql("""
    (SELECT value, group
    FROM originalDf)
    UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM originalDf)
        LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(SEQUENCE(0, 5, 1)) temp_table AS group)
    """)
```

**Analysis**
*result1*

```sh
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Union
:- LogicalRDD [value#551, group#552L], false
+- Project [value#551, group#624]
   +- Generate explode(sequence(0, 5, Some(1), Some(Asia/Taipei))), true, [group#624]
      +- Deduplicate [value#551]
         +- Project [value#551]
            +- LogicalRDD [value#551, group#552L], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
value: string, group: bigint
Union
:- Project [value#551, group#552L]
:  +- LogicalRDD [value#551, group#552L], false
+- Project [value#636, cast(group#637 as bigint) AS group#638L]
   +- Project [value#551 AS value#636, group#624 AS group#637]
      +- Project [value#551, group#624]
         +- Generate explode(sequence(0, 5, Some(1), Some(Asia/Taipei))), true, [group#624]
            +- Deduplicate [value#551]
               +- Project [value#551]
                  +- LogicalRDD [value#551, group#552L], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Union
:- LogicalRDD [value#551, group#552L], false
+- Project [value#551, cast(group#624 as bigint) AS group#638L]
   +- Generate explode(org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@bb501947), true, [group#624]
      +- Aggregate [value#551], [value#551]
         +- Project [value#551]
            +- LogicalRDD [value#551, group#552L], false

== Physical Plan ==
Union
:- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[value#551,group#552L]
+- *(4) Project [value#551, cast(group#624 as bigint) AS group#638L]
   +- Generate explode(org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@bb501947), [value#551], true, [group#624]
      +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[value#551], functions=[], output=[value#551])
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(value#551, 200), true, [id=#2107]
            +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[value#551], functions=[], output=[value#551])
               +- *(2) Project [value#551]
                  +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[value#551,group#552L]
```

*result2*

```sh
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Union
:- 'Project ['value, 'group]
:  +- 'UnresolvedRelation [originalDf]
+- 'Project [*]
   +- 'Generate 'EXPLODE('SEQUENCE(0, 5, 1)), false, temp_table, ['group]
      +- 'SubqueryAlias __auto_generated_subquery_name
         +- 'Distinct
            +- 'Project ['value]
               +- 'UnresolvedRelation [originalDf]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
value: string, group: bigint
Union
:- Project [value#425, group#426L]
:  +- Project [value#425, group#426L]
:     +- SubqueryAlias originaldf
:        +- LogicalRDD [value#425, group#426L], false
+- Project [value#511, cast(group#512 as bigint) AS group#513L]
   +- Project [value#425 AS value#511, group#510 AS group#512]
      +- Project [value#425, group#510]
         +- Generate explode(sequence(0, 5, Some(1), Some(Asia/Taipei))), false, temp_table, [group#510]
            +- SubqueryAlias __auto_generated_subquery_name
               +- Distinct
                  +- Project [value#425]
                     +- SubqueryAlias originaldf
                        +- LogicalRDD [value#425, group#426L], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Union
:- LogicalRDD [value#425, group#426L], false
+- Project [value#425, cast(group#510 as bigint) AS group#513L]
   +- Generate explode(org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@bb501947), false, temp_table, [group#510]
      +- Aggregate [value#425], [value#425]
         +- Project [value#425]
            +- LogicalRDD [value#425, group#426L], false

== Physical Plan ==
Union
:- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[value#425,group#426L]
+- *(4) Project [value#425, cast(group#510 as bigint) AS group#513L]
   +- Generate explode(org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@bb501947), [value#425], false, [group#510]
      +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[value#425], functions=[], output=[value#425])
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(value#425, 200), true, [id=#1824]
            +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[value#425], functions=[], output=[value#425])
               +- *(2) Project [value#425]
                  +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[value#425,group#426L]
```

**Some Notes You Might Find Useful**

1. If you want to make vertical combination, please do note that via function API (as you use the Scala function API in this case), `unionAll` is deprecated. Just keep in mind whether you want to move duplication or not after the combination. For detail, you could take a look at [SPARK-14088](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14088).
2. The difference between `explode()` and `explode_outer()` is that the latter one keeps null/empty values.
3. There are 5 modes in `explain()` since Spark 3.0.0, i.e., `simple`, `extended`, `codegen`, `cost`, and `simple`. You'll get some insight with different modes from the last lazily-evaluated DataFrame.
4. [Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-lateral-view.html) of LATERAL VIEW